# '$' before external stylesheet or script file?

Tags: javascript, html

I have never seen this before and ran into it today; I am wondering what the below means -- and why it is used. The syntax of the '*$*' before the external file path.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="$views/css/buttons.css">
```

Comment: Well, $ is a valid symbol for file names. It doesn't necessarily have to mean something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just part of the filename -- it's not anything special.

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible that your are looking at a template file that generates HTML? The `$views` could be a variable in that template system. Examples of templating languages that use this syntax are WebMacro, Velocity, and Cheetah.

Or is it possible this is a snippet of PHP that is using string interpolation to generate HTML?  In that case, `$views` is a PHP variable.